# How to solve segmentation fault when trying to mutate create AdGroupAd for app_ad in google api (php)

Tags: php, segmentation-fault, google-ads-api

I'm trying to create an AdGroupAd using an existing groupAd, and i'm getting a "segmentation fault" error message
I've been at this for more than a day now, but the lack of details on the error just makes this insane to understand what's wrong

running on docker

Client library: v5.0.0

Google Ads API: v5.0

PHP 7.4.12 (cli) (built: Nov 5 2020 20:24:10) ( NTS )

Zend Engine v3.4.0,

ionCube PHP Loader + ionCube24 v10.4.4

Zend OPcache v7.4.12

protobuff 3.14.0

grpc 1.33.1

my code: Assume createAdGroupAd() is called with a valid resource name for an adGroup in the $adGroup parameter
and the type is CreativeType_Asset::TYPE_YOUTUBE in this case (although i tried with both types and both give out the error)

```
public function createAdGroupAd($adGroup, $data) {
        $service = $this->client->getAdGroupAdServiceClient();

        $ad = $this->createAd($data, $data['asset']->type);

        $adGroupAd = new AdGroupAd([
            'ad' => $ad,
            'status' => AdGroupAdStatus::PAUSED,
            'ad_group' =>  $adGroup
        ]);

        $adGroupAdOperation = new AdGroupAdOperation();
        $adGroupAdOperation->setCreate($adGroupAd);

        //this is the call causing the error
        $response = $service->mutateAdGroupAds(
            $this->customerId,
            [$adGroupAdOperation]
        );

        return $response->getResults()->count() > 0 ? $response->getResults()[0]->getResourceName() : null;
    }

    public function createAd($data, $adType = null) {
        $service = $this->client->getAdServiceClient();
        $appAdInfo = new AppAdInfo([
            'headlines' => array_map(function ($headline) {
                new AdTextAsset(['text' => $headline]);
            }, [$data['creative']->title1, $data['creative']->title2]),
            'descriptions' => array_map(function ($description) {
                new AdTextAsset(['text' => $description]);
            }, [$data['creative']->description1, $data['creative']->description2])
        ]);

        switch ($adType) {
            case CreativeType_Asset::TYPE_IMAGE:
                $appAdInfo->setImages([new AdImageAsset(['asset' => $data['assetResourceName']])]);
                break;
            case CreativeType_Asset::TYPE_YOUTUBE:
                $appAdInfo->setYoutubeVideos([new AdVideoAsset(['asset' => $data['assetResourceName']])]);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return new Ad([
            'app_ad' => $appAdInfo,
            'type' => AdType::APP_AD]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was missing "return" statements in the array_map functions of the AppAdInfo building part.